# The angularjs directive ngrepeat is not working with object in angular wizard

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to angularjs and I'm using version 1.5.8 (i can't upgrade). I'm trying to use ng-repeat with

[angular wizard](https://github.com/angular-wizard/angular-wizard) based on [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/SiFeXXPITHoykk1q3hvE?p=preview&preview) example. However, my steps for the questions `ng-repeat="question in vm.questions"`, do not repeat. Below is my code. Please advice.

html

```
<form class="login-form idoquestion" name="idForm" id="idForm" novalidate ng-controller="iCtrl as vm">
<wizard hide-indicators="true" indicators-position="top">
    <wz-step wz-title="Starting">
        <h3 class="form-title">Begin</h3><br />
        <div class="form-actions" style="padding-bottom: 55px">
            <div class="pull-right" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <button type="submit" wz-next ng-disabled="!vm.disableNext" class="btn blue"> Next </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step wz-title="Question" ng-repeat="question in vm.questions">
        <h3 class="form-title">Question {{$index}}</h3>
        <input type="radio" name="questionName" ng-value="question.answers" ng-model="vm.selectedAnswers[$index]" />
        <label>{{ question.questionName }}</label>
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <button type="submit" wz-next class="btn blue"> Next </button>
        </div>
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step wz-title="More steps">
        <span>Finish</span><br /><br />
        <div class="form-actions" style="padding-bottom: 55px">
            <div class="pull-right" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <button type="submit" wz-next class="btn blue" ng-click="vm.finishWizard()"> Exit </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </wz-step>
</wizard>
</form>
```

controller

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('iCtrl', iCtrl);

    iCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$window', '$location', '$routeParams', 'modalService', 'userSession'];

function iCtrl($scope, $window, $location, $routeParams, modalService, userSession) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.questions = [];
    vm.answers = [];
    vm.selectedAnswers = [];
    vm.disableNext = true;

    init();
    function getQuestions() {
        var q1 = {
            questionName: 'At which of the following addresses have you lived?',
            answers: ['4344 BACKTRAIL DR', '113 BIRCH DR', '5015 B U BOWMAN DR', 'None of the above']
        }
        var q2 = {
            questionName: 'What is the approximate square footage of the property at 222333 PEACHTREE PLACE?',
            answers: ['1,000 or less', '1,001 - 1,500', '1,501 - 2,000', 'None of the above']
        }
        var q3 = {
            questionName: 'At From whom did you purchase the property at 222333 PEACHTREE PLACE?',
            answers: ['4344 BACKTRAIL DR', '113 BIRCH DR', '5015 B U BOWMAN DR', 'None of the above']
        }
        vm.questions.push(q1);
        vm.questions.push(q2);
        vm.questions.push(q3);
        vm.selectedAnswers = new Array(vm.questions.length);
    }

    vm.finishWizard = function finishWizard() {
        console.log('Wizard finished!');
    }

    function init() {
        getQuestions();
    }
}
})();
```

Comment: Make sure that you used the directive `ng-controller="iCtrl as vm"` in your html (before using `ng-repeat=""`)

Comment: @MaxMartynov I added it, cleared my cache and refreshed, but it still did not work.

Comment: What about the directive `ng-app=""`?

Comment: It would be great if you create a code snippet where you can reproduce the problem online, because the code pieces you provided look correct

Answer (score 0):

So the issue had nothing to due with the code but rather in issue with dynamic steps. Since the steps are dynamic, they are inserted at the end. I found out through this [post](https://github.com/angular-wizard/angular-wizard/issues/172#issuecomment-335821111).